# How to press inside the rectangle. And eliminate one code

Tags: processing

The problem I am having with my code is that. I am trying to press the left corner of the rectangle and eliminate one code. But two of my codes gets eliminate. And the rectangles are side to side but with little stuff to separate them.

I have tried to change the logic operators. But I keep running in to the same problem

```
//**Here is my code**//


color lb=#1EACE3;//Fill in light blue
color dp=#461CC6;//Fill in dark purple
color lp=#E81CCD;//Fill in light pink
color hp=#C414D8;//Fill in hot pink
color aq=#00FFFF;//Fill in aqua
color te=#008080;//Fill in teal
color db=#140FD1;//Fill in dark blue
color r=#D32815;//Fill in red
color dbb=#1556D3;//Fill in dark and light blue
color title=#8C10CB;//Fill in purple
void setup() {
  background(te);
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw() {
  println(mouseX, mouseY);
  if ((mouseX<=9)&&(mouseY<=12)) {
    background(hp);
  }

  noStroke();//No outline color for the shapes 
  fill(hp);//fill in hot pink

  //**This is the border**//
  fill(db);
  //Funtion Box**//
  rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
  rect(52, 1, 50, 50);
  //**instructions Box**//
  rect(24, 430, 500, 150);

  //**This is the title**//
  fill(title);//fill in light purple
  textSize(30);//Text size
  text("King Castle", 241, 55);//title
  //**What to do**//
  textSize(9.99);
  text("If you want to use the draw. hold down the mouse and start drawing if you let go it will stop", 30, 450);
  if (mousePressed==false) {
    cursor(WAIT);
  }
}
void mouseDragged() {
  if ((mousePressed==true)&&(mouseY<=61)&&(mouseY<=9)) {
    background(te);
  }
  fill(aq);//Fill in aqure 
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 30);
  cursor(CROSS);
}
```

When I press inside the rectangle both of my codes get eliminate.

Comment: I don't understand your question well can you please explain better if you can, and by the way check the line 47, maybe you mean (mouseY<=61)&&(mouseY>=9) instead of both of them being inferior or equal?

Comment: I am trying to call up my code then when you hover over the rectangle in the left corner of it. It will change the background. (sorry my English is poor)

Answer (score 0):

```
//**This is my new code**//

color lb = #ADD8E6;//Fill in light blue
color pq = #AFEEEE;//Fill in paleturquoise
color te = #008080;//Fill in teal
color dt = #00CED1;//Fill in darkturquoise
color fb = #D32815;//Fill in firebrick
color y = #FFE708;//Fill in yellow
color p = #DDA0DD ;//Fill in plum
color pp=#FFDAB9;//Fill in peachpuff
color ma = #66CDAA;//Fill in mediumaquamarine

void setup() {
  background(pp);
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw() {
  println(mouseX, mouseY);

  noStroke();//No outline color for the shapes 

  //**This is the border**//
  fill(lb);
  //Funtion Box**//
  rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
  rect(55, 0, 50, 50);

  //**instructions Box**//
  rect(24, 430, 500, 150);

  //**This is the title**//
  fill(fb);//fill in light purple
  textSize(30);//Text size
  text("King Castle", 241, 55);//title

  //**What to do**//
  textSize(10.09);
  text("If you want to draw. hold down the mouse and start drawing if you let go it will stop", 30, 450);//First Command 
  text("If you want to change the colour. Use the Q, W, E, R", 30, 460);//Second Command
  text("You have to hold down the mouse, and select your colour. And start moving the mouse, to draw.", 30, 469);//Third Command
  text("If you want the colour paleturquoise use. Key Q.", 30, 477);
  text("If you want to reset the colour back to default. Use the key W.", 30, 486);

  if (mousePressed==false) {
    cursor(WAIT);
  }
}
void mouseDragged() {  

  noStroke();//No outline color for the shapes 
  cursor(ARROW);//Curosr image to arrow
  fill(pq);//peachpuff
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 30);//cursor

  if (keyCode==87) {
    noStroke();//No outline color for the shapes 
    fill(pq);//peachpuff
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 30);
    cursor(ARROW);//Curosr image to arrow
  }

  if (keyCode==81) {
    noStroke();//No outline color for the shapes 
    fill(p);//plum
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 30);
    cursor(ARROW);//Curosr image to arrow
  }

  //**Commands For the rect. When Pressed**//
  if ((mousePressed==true)&&(mouseX<=11)&&(mouseY<=12)) {
    background(dt);
  }

  if ((mousePressed==true)&&(mouseY<=66)&&(mouseX<=14)) {
    background(ma);
  }
}
```